# issues updating firmware using fwupdmgr update

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, firmware, fwupd

I am using ubuntu 18 with a pc (asus motherboard)
and trying to update the firmware using [this](https://itsfoss.com/update-firmware-ubuntu/)

After starting the service using those commands nothing happens

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo service fwupd start
sudo fwupdmgr refresh
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

Nothing happens

I also tried the following, and nothing happend

```
sudo fwupdmgr update -v
sudo fwupdmgr update --force
sudo fwupdmgr update --show-all-devices
```

Nothing happens, no output no nothing. 
Ideas?

Comment: Also nothing in the /var/log/syslog. My fwupdmgr version is 1.2.5, efivar version 37, gusb 0.3.0.

Answer (score 5):

**tldr;** `fwupdmgr get-updates` should show you available firmware updates *(from official channels)* for all of your supported & connected devices.

If it shows you no output at all, it means that no updates were found *(usually not published by the vendor)* into the official channels *([fwupd.org](https://fwupd.org/))*.

You can use `fwupdmgr get-devices` to get a list of updateable devices.

Also, if your device vendor has published a *xxxxxxxx.cab* file to be used to update from linux, you can use `fwupdmgr install xxxxxxxx.cab` to schedule the firmware update upon next reboot.

This was tested less than a week ago *(2019-06-29)* in a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga X1 3rd gen1. `fwupdmgr get-updates` shows highest BIOS version as 1.34, but I manually installed version 1.35 from a downloaded *xxxxxxxx.cab* file from Lenovo's support site.

*Note: new firmware updates should also appear into updates section of gnome software app.*

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please check this out https://github.com/rhboot/fwupdate/issues/133

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like you have no hardware supported by LVFS. [Asus does not currently use this service](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/vendorlist)

Calling `fwupdmgr get-devices` will show you all devices supported by LVFS on your system. If there's no output, then there's just no devices supported.

Comment: `fwupdmgr get-devices` lists a lot of devices. My hardware is obviously supported by LVFS and firmware updates worked before. There are new cab files for my system listed on the LVFS site. Yet, fwupdmgr doesn't see them.

Comment: It lists nothing, how can I update firmware in this case?

Comment: @user1234567 can you please check this out https://github.com/rhboot/fwupdate/issues/133

Comment: @PiotrKolaczkowski, I guess you can download new cabs that you see on the site, check downloaded with `fwupdmgr get-details FILE` and if output suits you `fwupdmgr install FILE [DEVICE-ID]`